# Sending my first transaction, Help!... Unexpected string error

Tags: transactions

I'm trying to send some ethers to another account, but I'm having some errors, please help me

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you missed the colon after the "to". So it should be `from: eth.coinbase, to:`

Comment: thank you very much. It worked, except for that I needed more gas. I increased the gas to 21000, but then it told me: 
ReferenceError: 'web3toWei' is not defined
        at <anonymous>:1:98

Comment: Did you miss the "." after the web3 this time?  web3.toWei(4.99, 'ether')

Comment: this is what I wrote:

eth.sendTransaction({from:eth.coinbase, to: "0x4bf4c01831EB2Bf63e0D5318Ff6eEd3
9f892A2fC" ,value: web3toWei(4.99, "ether") gas:21000})

Comment: You need a dot between web3 and toWei. See my previous comment.

Comment: Sorry, now I'm having problems with the gas... if i put 5003 it is too low, and 5004 exceeds the limit...
eth.sendTransaction({from:eth.coinbase, to: "0x4bf4c01831EB2Bf63e0D5318Ff6eEd3
9f892A2fC" ,value: web3.toWei(4.99, "ether") gas:5003})

Error: intrinsic gas too low

    at web3.js:3104:20
    at web3.js:6191:15
    at web3.js:5004:36
    at <anonymous>:1:1

Comment: ianinini, when we get this done, you'll have 0.1 eth

Comment: What you're reporting is unexpected. Just remove the "gas: 5004" altogether. Then you'll get charged the market rate for a transaction.

Comment: not warking, man :(
> eth.sendTransaction({from:eth.coinbase, to: "0x4bf4c01831EB2Bf63e0D5318Ff6eEd3
9f892A2fC" ,value: web3.toWei(4.99, "ether")})

Error: exceeds block gas limit
    at web3.js:3104:20
    at web3.js:6191:15
    at web3.js:5004:36
    at <anonymous>:1:1

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with the command now. Have you got more than 4.99 ether in the eth.coinbase wallet? 4.99 is the amount the recipient will receive. There needs to be more than 4.99 in the from wallet to cover the gas cost (which is always payed by the sender).

Comment: Yes... I have 5 eth, that's why I'm sending 4.99, may be I should try 4.9 or even 4.5, just to see if it works

Comment: I think it is too late :( ... when unblocking I compromised my password, now the balance shows 0. When I check here: https://etherchain.org/account/0x1949884960ee8b68376b5e963977ed874f1c01c1#txsent , my account shows no transactions, no balance... I'm really sad, it was a lot of money I was so lucky to get. Is there a way to check the transactions in geth?

Comment: Sorry to hear that Mosco. You must be able to get a list of all transactions that have transferred ether from a given addrees. But I have absolutely no idea how. Sorry. (I don't think it will help you get your money back.)